# Android : callback received in first activity , not in second

Tags: android, callback

lets say I have a really simple interface :

```
interface Result {
    fun success(data : String)
    fun onError(e : Exception) }
```

I have MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Result {
}
```

and second class  - lets say :

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Result {
}
```

In both activities implementation is exactly the same. However, I can only receive callback in Main Activity. When I launch second activity and run action I can see logs from MainActivity but not from SecondActivity. Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task which you launch from `MainActivity` to which you have passed `this` which is the instance of `Result` interface inside the instance of `MainActivity`, So the callback is received at the `MainActivitys'` callback.

If you launch the same task from the `SecondActivity` and pass `this` then it will refer to the instance of the `Result` interface inside the instance of `SecondActivity`, then you will get the callback in the `SecondActivity`.

**Keep in mind that if you get back to `MainActivity`, before the launched task from `SecondActivity` finished then you may get an`NPE`.**

`interface` and `abstract` can not have direct instances, the class that `implement` or `extends` them will create their instance, for each instance of the implementing or extending class a new instance of `interface` or `abstract` class will be created inside the instance of the implementing class.